# Read a text file into a struct array with functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, file, struct

so I have this file:

```
Jane
18
5.3
John
23
5.8
```

and I need to create a program to store this two persons details on a array of structs.

I have done this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
     char name[100];
     int age;
     float height;
} PERSON;


main()
{
    PERSON *X = NULL;
    FILE *f;
    char ch;
    int lines = 1;

    f = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

    while ((ch = fgetc(f)) !=EOF)
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
            lines++;
    }

    rewind(f);

    X = (PERSON*) malloc ((lines/3) * sizeof(PERSON));

    StoreInArray(X, f, lines);
}

StoreInArray(PERSON *X, FILE *f, int lines)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i < lines/3; i++)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%s%d%f", (*(X+i)).name[100], &(*(X+i)).age, &(*(X+i)).height);
    }

//for testing//
 for (i=0; i < lines/3; i++)
     printf("%s\n%d \n%f\n",X[i].name[100], X[i].age, X[i].height);
}
```

But all it prints is:

```
(null)
0
0.000000
```

If you could help me figure out what is wrong I'd be very appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: After your initial `fgetc` loop, the file is at EOF. Add `rewind(f)` before calling `StoreInArray`

Comment: Thank you! I've added it. I just realized that the "lines" variable isn't incrementing tho

Comment: I would also suggest using `PERSON *p = X + i;` prior to the fscanf() and printf(), so you can write: `fscanf(f, "%s%d%f", p->name, &p->age, &p->height);` for improved readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd compile with `-Wall -O2` to catch warnings, which would have pointed out an error.

In your `fscanf` and `printf`, you don't want `name[100]` but `name`. You want to point to the `name` *array*, but `name[100]` is a single `char` [fetching *past* the end of the array (i.e.) undefined behavior], and would be flagged by the compiler.

Here's a version of your code with the bugs annotated/corrected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float height;
} PERSON;

void StoreInArray(PERSON * X, FILE * f, int lines);

int
main()
{
    PERSON *X = NULL;
    FILE *f;
    char ch;
    int lines = 1;

    f = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

    while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n')
            lines++;
    }

    rewind(f);

    X = (PERSON *) malloc((lines / 3) * sizeof(PERSON));

    StoreInArray(X, f, lines);

    return 0;
}

void
StoreInArray(PERSON * X, FILE * f, int lines)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < lines / 3; i++) {
#if 0
        fscanf(f, "%s%d%f", (*(X + i)).name[100], &(*(X + i)).age, &(*(X + i)).height);
#else
        fscanf(f, "%s%d%f", (*(X + i)).name, &(*(X + i)).age, &(*(X + i)).height);
#endif
    }

//for testing//
    for (i = 0; i < lines / 3; i++) {
#if 0
        printf("%s\n%d \n%f\n", X[i].name[100], X[i].age, X[i].height);
#else
        printf("%s\n%d \n%f\n", X[i].name, X[i].age, X[i].height);
#endif
    }
}
```

---

Note that using `*(X + i)).name` is cumbersome, so here's a simplified and more readable version that uses an extra pointer variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float height;
} PERSON;

void StoreInArray(PERSON * X, FILE * f, int lines);

int
main()
{
    PERSON *X = NULL;
    FILE *f;
    char ch;
    int lines = 1;

    f = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

    while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n')
            lines++;
    }

    rewind(f);

    X = (PERSON *) malloc((lines / 3) * sizeof(PERSON));

    StoreInArray(X, f, lines);

    return 0;
}

void
StoreInArray(PERSON * X, FILE * f, int lines)
{
    int i = 0;
    PERSON *p;

    p = X;
    for (i = 0;  i < lines / 3;  i++, p++)
        fscanf(f, "%s%d%f", p->name, &p->age, &p->height);

//for testing//
    p = X;
    for (i = 0;  i < lines / 3;  i++, p++)
        printf("%s\n%d \n%f\n", p->name, p->age, p->height);
}
```

---

It isn't really necessary to preread the file to get a line count. It is possible to grow your array dynamically, as lines are read in, using `realloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float height;
} PERSON;

int
main()
{
    PERSON *X = NULL;
    FILE *f;
    int i;
    PERSON *p;
    int count = 0;

    f = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

    while (1) {
        X = realloc(X,sizeof(PERSON) * (count + 1));
        p = &X[count];

        if (fscanf(f, "%s%d%f", p->name, &p->age, &p->height) == EOF)
            break;

        ++count;
    }

    fclose(f);

    // trim the array
    X = realloc(X,sizeof(PERSON) * count);

    p = X;
    for (i = 0;  i < count;  i++, p++)
        printf("%s\n%d \n%f\n", p->name, p->age, p->height);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's a further refinement that reduces the number of `realloc` calls needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float height;
} PERSON;

int
main()
{
    PERSON *X = NULL;
    FILE *f;
    int i;
    PERSON *p;
    size_t count = 0;
    size_t alloc = 0;

    f = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

    while (1) {
        if (count >= alloc) {
            alloc += 100;
            X = realloc(X,sizeof(PERSON) * alloc);
        }

        p = &X[count];

        if (fscanf(f, "%s%d%f", p->name, &p->age, &p->height) == EOF)
            break;

        ++count;
    }

    fclose(f);

    // trim the array to what was actually used
    X = realloc(X,sizeof(PERSON) * count);

    p = X;
    for (i = 0;  i < count;  i++, p++)
        printf("%s\n%d \n%f\n", p->name, p->age, p->height);

    return 0;
}
```